# JSP Default object validation

Tags: java, jsp, session

I was working on a project using MVC desing having JSP as view layer.
I was testing the result of session, applicaton and request object available to JSP. 
I have written the following code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%! int result = 0;
        int add_request(String num1, String num2){
            if((num1 != null && num2 !=null) && (!num1.isEmpty() && !num2.isEmpty()))
                result = Integer.parseInt(num1)+Integer.parseInt(num2);
        return result;
    }

    int div_session(String number, String number1){
        if((number != null && number1 != null) && (!number.isEmpty() && !number1.isEmpty()))
                return (Integer.parseInt(number)/Integer.parseInt(number1));
        return 0;
    }

    int mult_context(String number, String number1){
        if((number != null && number1 != null) && (!number.isEmpty() && !number1.isEmpty()))
                return (Integer.parseInt(number)*Integer.parseInt(number1));
        return 0;
    }

    %>

    <div align="center">
        <form>
            Number: <input type="text" name="num1" /> <br>
            Number: <input type="text" name="num2" />
            <div align="center">
             <input type="submit" >
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>

    <%
        ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
        String firstnum = request.getParameter("num1");
        String secondnum = request.getParameter("num2");
        if((firstnum != null && secondnum != null) && (!firstnum.isEmpty() && !secondnum.isEmpty()))
        {
            session.setAttribute("test1", firstnum);
            session.setAttribute("test2", secondnum);
            context.setAttribute("test1", firstnum);
            context.setAttribute("test2", secondnum);
            application.setAttribute("test1", firstnum);
            application.setAttribute("test2", secondnum);
        }
    %>
    Result:<br>

    <br>Add request: <%= add_request(request.getParameter("num1"), request.getParameter("num2")) %>
    <br>Division session: <%= div_session((String)session.getAttribute("test1"), (String)session.getAttribute("test2")) %>
    <br>Multiplication context: <%= mult_context((String)context.getAttribute("test1"), (String)context.getAttribute("test2")) %>
    <br>Application Result: <%= mult_context((String)application.getAttribute("test1"), (String)application.getAttribute("test2")) %>

</body>
</html>
```

The desired output was:

Number : 120
Number : 20

Add result: 140
Division Session: 6
Multiplication Context: 2400
Multiplication application: 2400

And when I resubmit then parameter passed to request object is null so add result should be zero. if I open a new tab a acces the url without parameter then add result should be zero. When I open an other browser then Division session should be zero. but all is coming the same.

Because as per theory only session and application/context object are persistent between multiple request and only context is persistent through multiple session.

Guys where I am going wrong. 
Thanks.

Comment: all seems to be fine.

Comment: If I refresh then parameter num1 and num2 will be null so add method will show 0 but it is showing the last result its not updating the result in next request. so does the session and application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a instance variable of the Servlet instance that was created from your translated JSP.

```
<%! int result = 0
```

You need to reload  your JSP or your web app in order to get back zero.
In Tomcat(see work folder) that looks like the following

```
public final class test_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent,
             org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceImports {

   int result = 0;  
   ...
}
```

Therefore in your add_request method, when the parameters are empty, the persisted value of result is returned.

Answer (score 1):

See, 
This is happen because of `Scope` concept.

`JSP` has there are the scopes more likey speak then **from narrow to broad way**:

```
1. request
2. page
3. session
4. application
```

Now, as i knew then,

When some `parameter` going to fetch let's say,

> from request going to fetch "num1" & "num2" (which are already set in
>   session+application scope while first request made) then,
>
> if it's not found(really not found when page refresh) then it's try to
>   find out it from broader scope if it's there then.

*So , finally here in your case,*

> if `num1` or `num2` not found from request(when page refresh) it's
>   start to search from next level of broader scope if present then or
>   not(**broader than request scope**).
>
> See, it's searching direction is to next-next broader scope untill not
>   find finally not find anywhere then returns null,
>
> so it's getting from session then it's won't go to search into
>   application scope.

**Thanks.**

**UPDATED**

please do following changes into your code...

```
int add_request(String num1, String num2){

            if((num1 != null && num2 !=null) && (!num1.isEmpty() && !num2.isEmpty()))
                result = Integer.parseInt(num1)+Integer.parseInt(num2);
            else
                result = 0;

        return result;
```

> and from Query-String clear appended parameter and hit-Enter key from
>   key-board you will get proper result what you are expecting.

Comment: Fine that request.getParameter("num1") searches the parameter broader scopes but I have saved the object with different name i.e. on form parameter name is num1, num2 but in session and application the name of parameter is test1 , test2 then how does the mapping happens.

Comment: @AbhijatyaSingh see my UPDATED section... you are correct there is not same name for different scope. pardon me..!! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code for add_request. It works for me!

```
int add_request(String num1, String num2) {
        if ((num1 != null && num2 != null)
                && (!num1.isEmpty() && !num2.isEmpty()))
            return (Integer.parseInt(num1) + Integer.parseInt(num2));
        return 0;
    }
```

In your code, only add option is not working correctly. Actually Division option is working fine as expected(In different browsers, session is not carried). If you make the above change in your code, all the scope will work as expected.

Comment: Exactly. The "result" instance member is not even needed.